# Cannot sync ringtone

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone, ios

I have iTunes 11, I'm trying to sync a ringtone to my iPhone, but the ringtone is not added to my ringtones folder (settings->sounds->ringtone) in iOS. The file has a m4r format, and it's currently shown in the "tones" tab in Itunes:

[image]

I tried to sync my iPhone many times, and also selected the "tones" option in iTunes preferences under the "general" tab. But I still can't find my song to my ringtones folder !

Answer (score 2):

Try to

- move the ringtones from iTunes to the Desktop (or any other "safe" place)
- delete them from iTunes and sync
- copy them back into iTunes and sync again

It worked for me this way.

Answer (score 0):

Go on your iTunes and go to the music tab at the top of the page. Then go over to the right side of screen and select songs. Go all the way to the bottom of the list of songs and you'll find your ringtones there. You have to uncheck all the ringtones in that music file. Now go and sync your phone again and it'll put all of them on your phone.